# mute sound through phone speaker Android api

Tags: android

I want the to mute all sounds coming through the phone speaker but keep the sounds going through the headphones.  Is this possible?

I was looking at:
setMicrophoneMute(true);
and
setSpeakerphoneOn(false);

but neither seem to have any affect.  Is this even possible?  I have this permission in my manifest:

I couldn't see any methods that would accomplish what I want in the audio manager but maybe I just don't understand the api.